# Web Api User.Identity.Name

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Another question from me, yay!

Ok, so I have this code:

```
public class TokenMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var token = request.Headers.GetValues("Authorization-Token").FirstOrDefault();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent("Missing Authorization-Token")
                };
            });

        try
        {
            var user = UserRepository.GetUsers().FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == RSAClass.Decrypt(token));
            if (user == null)
                return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                    {
                        Content = new StringContent("Unauthorized User")
                    };
                });

            var identity = new GenericIdentity(user.UserName);
            var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);

            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
            if (HttpContext.Current != null)
                HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
        }
        catch (RSAClass.RSAException)
        {
            return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent("Error encountered while attempting to process authorization token")
                };
            });
        }

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

and it works perfectly.
If I call the api using my jQuery like so:

```
function GetAllCategories() {
    var credentials = '@ViewBag.encrypted';

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:18904/api/Categories",
        type: "GET",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization-Token", credentials);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, category) {
                var row = '<tr><td>' + category.DisplayName + '</td><td>' + category.DateCreated + '</td><td>' + category.AssetCount + '</td><td>' + category.CategoryCount + '</td></tr>';
                $('#categories').append(row);
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
}
```

I get a nice list of categories. Ace.
Now As you can see I am setting the CurrentPrincipal and the Current.User.
In my CategoriesController I have access to my User.Identity which is great.

My problem is this:
I have my own Profile which has lots of other information stored with it so the generic MembershipUser is not enough. So how can I set my Profile so it will persist. For example I want to set something that will persist in the MessageHandler like setting the HttpContext.Current.User or Thread.CurrentPrincipal.

Can anyone give me a hand?

Cheers,

/r3plica

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar, but I implemented my own IIdentity instead of GenericIdentity.

```
var identity = new ApiIdentity(user);

public class ApiIdentity : IIdentity
{
    public ApiIdentity(UserModel user)
    {
        User = user;
    }

    public UserModel User { get; set; }

    #region IIdentity Members

    public string Name
    {
        get { return User.UserId.ToString(); }
    }

    public string AuthenticationType
    {
        get { return "Basic"; }
    }

    public bool IsAuthenticated
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then in my BaseApiController I can access the identity and use it like Identity.User.xxx :

```
    public ApiIdentity Identity
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as ApiIdentity; }
    }
```